# Is it possible to reference an attribute of the current element in another attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have the following HTML code which works (it uses angular-ui/ui-router state) but looks too ugly because of 3 repetitions of the same expression:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="menuitem in menuitems"
                 is-open="$state.includes('chapters.item', {'chapter':'{{$stateParams.chapter}}', 'itemId':'{{menuitem.id}}'})"
                 ng-class="{'group-open': $state.includes('chapters.item', {'chapter':'{{$stateParams.chapter}}', 'itemId':'{{menuitem.id}}'}),
                    'group-closed': !$state.includes('chapters.item', {'chapter':'{{$stateParams.chapter}}', 'itemId':'{{menuitem.id}}'})}">
```

It would be nice to reuse a value of is-open attribute in ng-class but I don't understand how to reference it correctly. I tried $attr('is-open') and $attr('isOpen') and several other ways but with no success. Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing the entire expression multiple times, create a scope variable that represent the `$state` includes. For example, in your controller:

```
$scope.isOpen = $state.includes('chapters.item', {'chapter':'{{$stateParams.chapter}}', 'itemId':'{{menuitem.id}}'});
```

and then in your html:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="menuitem in menuitems" is-open="isOpen" ng-class="{'group-open': isOpen, 'group-closed': !isOpen }">
```

Comment: Don't understand. isOpen should have a different value for each menuitem (note ng-repeat). Then I have to create a separate controller for each menuitem? How to do this? Isn't it too bulky? I simply wanted to access a DOM attribute from the DOM. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, depends on whether or not you can only have one open at a time. If not, just set `isOpen` to the menu item id, and if so, set an isOpen value on each item in `menuitems`.

Comment: Still unclear if it is possible to reference a DOM attribute from the HTML. If yes, then I don't need to create additional variables and controllers.